# What does "1, 2, 3, 5" refer to?

Tags: watch-dogs

This question contains ending spoilers:

> At the end of the game, after the credits, you see Maurice locked up in a garage, muttering the numbers "1, 2, 3, 5" to himself over and over again.

What does this mean?  I've seen a few theories:

> Someone in the audio logs mentioned putting the Fibonacci Sequence into ctOS to see if [..] subliminal messaging would cause people to see the numbers. Hence, Maurice saying the Fibonacci Sequence confirms that the 'experiment' [was] a success.  *([source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eP9EGX6PlGI&google_comment_id=z12ygrl5fra2fd5uv221d5zx5y3ytbm2r))*

another one:

> 1235 is the license plate from the car crash when Lena dies. *([source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eP9EGX6PlGI&google_comment_id=z12ygrl5fra2fd5uv221d5zx5y3ytbm2r))*

and another one:

> I'm assuming it's a reference to [1984](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nineteen_Eighty-Four) and Double Speak where they talk about how easily they could convince the population 2+2=5 if they wanted.  That combined with Defalt's subtitle being "twoplustwoequalsfive" leads to that. *([source](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/704529-watch-dogs/69332664))*

Do any of these theories have any merit? *(I'd go with the audio-log one, if that audio-log really exists)*

Comment: For anyone not familiar with the standard Fibonacci sequence, it starts with 0 and 1, and then after that each number is the sum of the previous two:
0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like, the audio log is right on the money.

In Angela Balik's audio log 10 (unlocked by doing ctOS Breach Contracts), you can hear that she is using it, to test if ctOS could be used to influence people.

She is right.

In the Missing Persons sidequest, you can see this [number sequence](http://watchdogs.wikia.com/wiki/Missing_Persons#Relevance_of_the_numbers) regularly, hinting that the killer is influenced by ctOS.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I believe it refers to a standard torturing technique (as we all know Jordi did lots of), where you make someone count to 5, but hurt them when they say 4. Eventually, it becomes difficult for the person to say 4 at all. That's why Maurice kept trying to say "12345" but would say "Shit" because he couldn't say 4.